# Why won't my serialized PostgreSQL array save to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

My schema looks like this:

```
create_table "products", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "elements_list",   default: [],    array: true
end
```

I am using Rails 4 and aiming to use PostgreSQL's array column type, so I do not declare `serialize :attribute, Class` in `product.rb`.

`@product` will save, but in doing so it discards the serialized array without returning an error. Why am I getting this strangeness? How do I fix it?

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.id
=> 1
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.description
=> nil
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.elements_list
=> []
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.elements_list.class
=> Array
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.id
=> 1
[6] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.description
=> nil
[7] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.elements_list
=> [1, 3]
[8] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.elements_list.class
=> Array
[9] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.update_attribute :description, "New description"
=> true
[10] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.save!
=> true
[11] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.description
=> "New description"
[12] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> Product.first.elements_list
=> []
[13] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Product::AddToElementsList>)> @product.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f80e3348490
 @base=
  #<Product id: 1, name: "product-1", created_at: "2014-07-02 00:47:23", updated_at: "2014-07-02 00:48:31", description: "New description", latest_url: nil, resetting_cache: "f", for_sale: true, for_consulting: false, questions_list: [], elements_list: [1, 3], versioning: false>,
 @messages={}>
```

**UPDATE**

I've got this working by switching from PostgreSQL'S array column type to Rail's serialized arrays, but I'm leaving the question here unless a PostgreSQL-based solution, if anyone has one, helps others.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :elements_list, Array
end

class ChangeProductElementsListToText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :products, :elements_list, :text
    change_column_default :products, :elements_list, nil
  end
end
```